# Prove that linear transformation is isomorphic, given the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

I've been trying to solve this question:

> Let $T :\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ be a linear transformation with the following characteristic polynomial:
> $p(x) = x^2 +2x -3$
>
> 1. Prove that the linear transformation $2T+I$ is an isomorphism
> 2. What is the characteristic polynomial of $T^3$?

I've found that the eigenvalues of the transformation $T$ are $\lambda_1 =1, \lambda_2 =-3$.

Therefore, T is an isomorphism. Can I claim that because T can have a representing matrix, the multiplication by scalar and addition of the identity matrix keep it an isomorphism?
$2·[T]_B+I$

Thank you!

Comment: Try to write down its inverse (in terms of $T$) explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**

Let $S=2T+I$, then $4T^2+8T-12I=0$ and so $(S-I)^2+4(S-I)-12I=0$ i.e. $S^2+2S-15I=0$. Therefore $S$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2+2x-15$ and is an isomorphism since $15\ne 0$.

**Q2**

Since $T$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-3\\\end{pmatrix}$,  $T^3$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-27\\\end{pmatrix}$ and therefore its characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x+27).$

**N.B. Regarding your idea of adding $I$**

This is not valid. As a simple example, imagine that your original matrix was $-I$. Adding $I$ would then reduce it to $0$.

Comment: N.B. The answer by @Tserno Aristide is neater than mine for the part of the question concerning $2T+I$. (But you should know both methods.)

Comment: Can you please explain why is $4T^2 + 8T -12I = 0$ ?
Also, thanks, I didn't think of this edge case.

Comment: I just multiplied its characteristic equation by 4

Comment: I understand. I just wasn't taught that the variable in the characteristic polynomial is actually the linear transformation.
It would only be the given eigenvalue that nullifies the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

$T^2+2T-3I=0$ implies that $T(T+2I)=3I$ and ${1\over 3}T(T+2I)=(2T+I){1\over 3}T=I$